# Avoid text to appear right under checkbox

Tags: css

How do I stop text that breaks to new line appear right under the checkbox?

```
[x] this is a text that
break.
```

How I want:

```
[x] this is how I want
   the text to appear.
```

HTML:

```
<input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label>text..</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 3: Improved Answer -** I reccomend using a flexbox as you only need one line of CSS and it is relatively responsive straight off the bat.

Simply wrap the input and label in a div and apply `display: flex;` like so:

```
<div>
   <input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
   <label>Text</label>
</div>

div {
    display: flex
}
```

See an example here https://jsfiddle.net/q5vv6bmj/1/

---

**Original Answer:**

Applying `position: absolute` to your label should fix this issue.

See my solution in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/px1h7Ltv/

**EDIT:** if you want to prevent labels overlapping then you can wrap them in a `<div>` tag and apply paddings or margins like this: https://jsfiddle.net/px1h7Ltv/3/ this isnt responsive.

**EDIT 2:** Alternatively you can apply the `position: absolute` to the `<input>` with a negative left value like so: https://jsfiddle.net/4d286j8h/2/

A better method than all of this might be to use a flexbox which at its most basic requires only one line of CSS and does all the work for you. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/q5vv6bmj/1/

Comment: Almost there, but it merges with other input+labels, like : https://jsfiddle.net/px1h7Ltv/2/ any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Alternatively try using a flexbox like this: https://jsfiddle.net/q5vv6bmj/1/

It can be a lot simpiler and it could cause less issues in the long run.

Comment: flex worked well, thanks. Tried many other solution, but it was somehow messy. I guess it was bootstrap or something that interfered.

Comment: Im glad I could help. I should have suggested flex straight off the bat but I only thought of it straight after I posted

Answer (score 3):

It can be done easily with flexbox. I also suggest to add `for=""` and `id=""` pairing to the label and checkbox for better accessibility.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.myCheckbox {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="container">
  <input id="myCheckbox_1" class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox">
  <label for="myCheckbox_1">this is how I want the text to appear.</label>
</p>
```

You can also wrap the checkbox in the label.

```css
.myLabel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.myCheckbox {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label class="myLabel">
  <input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox">
  this is how I want the text to appear.
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing the `<input>` inside of the `<label>`? Like this:

`<label><input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1"> text..</label>`

Comment: Still same issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Place your input inside the label and then apply the following CSS to your labels:

```
label {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-indent: -25px;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-indent: -25px;
}
```

```html
<label><input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tristique quis turpis at iaculis. Donec metus lacus, hendrerit nec egestas vitae, pulvinar vel mi. Nunc dolor lorem, rhoncus vitae justo vitae, elementum interdum urna. Etiam ultrices tellus efficitur, accumsan turpis sed, sodales ligula. Vestibulum dapibus accumsan ligula id luctus. Integer ut ultricies quam. Vestibulum sed varius nisi.</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table-cell`:

```css
.grp {
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.grp .myCheckbox, .grp label {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="grp">
    <input id="cb1" class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="cb1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grp">
    <input id="cb2" class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="cb2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
    </div>
  <div class="grp">
  <input id="cb3" class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="cb3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
  </div>
<form>
```